# How to set the extent of a rotated data frame from a rotated rectangle using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, java, .net, layouts

I use ArcObjects to produce a map document.

I have a rotated rectangle that I want to be the exact extent of my data frame.

[image]

So, I want to rotate the data frame with the same orientation than the rectangle, then fill the map space with the rectangle.

What I want:

[image]

I tried this code:

```
IPageLayout pageLayout = (IPageLayout)mapDocument.getActiveView();
IMap dataFrame = mapDocument.getMap(0);

IPolygon polygon = ...

// data frame rotation
double dataFrameRotation = -44.46035122650748; // (the polygon orientation in negative)
IActiveView activeView = (IActiveView)dataFrame;
activeView.getScreenDisplay().getDisplayTransformation().setRotation(dataFrameRotation);

// setting the extent
IEnvelope zoomToExtent = polygon.getEnvelope();
activeView.setExtent(zoomToExtent);
```

The problem I get is that `zoomToExtent` means the polygon extent in the map coordinate system (xMin, xMax, yMin, yMax), so the data frame is not enough zoomed.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Is your blue box polygon a graphic or actually a polygon in a FeatureClass?

Comment: It's a IPolygon object that I construct programmatically and I save in a feature class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code zooms to the extent of the polygon in the map then fits the whole page in page layout. This code gets the polygon and rotates it back to the horizontal (approximately 35° in my example) and then zooms to the extent of that rather than the original polygon extent which is much larger if the rectangle is rotated.

```vb
Public Sub Zoom()
    Dim pMXDocument As IMxDocument
    Set pMXDocument = ThisDocument

    Dim pPageLayout As IPageLayout
    Set pPageLayout = pMXDocument.PageLayout

    Dim pMap As IMap
    Set pMap = pMXDocument.FocusMap

    Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
    Set pActiveView = pMap

    ' Get layer with single polygon
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMap.Layer(0)
    Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
    Set pFeatureLayer = pLayer

    ' Get polygon and then its Envelope
    Dim pFeature As IFeature
    Set pFeature = pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.GetFeature(1)
    Dim pPolygon As IPolygon
    Set pPolygon = pFeature.Shape

    ' Get centroid
    Dim pArea As IArea
    Set pArea = pPolygon
    Dim pPoint As IPoint
    Set pPoint = pArea.Centroid

    ' Rotate polygon back to the horizontal (note units are in radians)
    Dim pTransform As ITransform2D
    Set pTransform = pPolygon
    pTransform.Rotate pPoint, 90

    ' Set Extent of Map to polygon Extent then
    ' Zoom to PageLayout
    pActiveView.Extent = pPolygon.Envelope
    pPageLayout.ZoomToWhole
End Sub
```

Rotated rectangle with graphic showing extent:

[image: Rotated rectangle with graphic showing extent]

Map rotated 35° to back rectangle horizontal:

[image: Map rotated 35° to back rectangle horizontal]

Correct Page Layout:

[image: Correct Page Layout]

Comment: Thanks for your response. This method works well if there is no rotations of the map. If the rectangle is oriented, its extent will be greater, then the map will not be enough zoomed.

Comment: I have edited my answer with new code. I think the issue is that you don't want the envelope you want the rectangle rotated back to the horizontal.

Comment: that's exactly what I need: to get the rectangle rotated back then zoomed in it. Thanks a lot.